# Is Block pruning applied on clustered table when you do complex expressions on the value instead of the column?

Tags: google-bigquery

Question about block pruning on a clustered table.

According the the following guide block pruning is not applied when you use a complex filter expression see:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables#do_not_use_clustered_columns_in_complex_filter_expressions

I have a table that is clustered on 'orders_date' if I run the following sql is block pruning applied?

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (((orders.order_date ) >= ((TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL (-3 * 7) DAY))) AND (orders.order_date ) < ((TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL (-3 * 7) DAY), INTERVAL (4 * 7) DAY)))))`

Comment: In you case, Yes (it will do block pruning). since there is no complex calculation on clustered field "order_date" itself..

Comment: If the answer helped somehow consider upvoting/accepting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be applied in your case because you are neither applying any complex function to your clustered column nor comparing your clustered column to another column. During the execution, the expression `(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL (-3 * 7) DAY))` for example will be evaluated and treated as a date parameter so we can say that in the end your **WHERE** clause would be as simple as `orders.order_date >= "YYYY-MM-DD" AND orders.order_date < "YYYY-MM-DD"`